# Resizing a YUI dial widget as page resizes

Tags: javascript, widget, yui

I'm using a [YUI dial widget](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/dial/) in a responsive page and trying to update the size of the dial after the screen has been resized so it always fits within its container.

I seem to be able to update the dial object's attributes (diameter, width, height, etc) but can't get the UI to update. Calling the `render()` and `syncUI()` methods doesn't seem to do anything.

Haven't really used YUI much before so maybe there's something obvious I'm missing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that stumbles across this question, I managed to solve it. I wasn't using the proper `set()` method for the diameter before calling `syncUI()` method on the dial object. Here's the solution:

```
$(window).smartresize(function() {
  var diameter = $('#container').width();
  dial.set('diameter', diameter);
  dial.syncUI();
});
```